# Configure Multiple OpenTSDB to use single HBase backend

Tags: hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

I have to configure multiple openTSDB to put data into a sinfle HBase. Out of all TSD, one would be running local to Hbase and others would be remote. For which I tried running TSD with the extra argument of --zkquorum=xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:YY, though it was able to connect but gave some exception inside. Can someone please tell me what all I have to configure to run multiple TSD to use single Hbase.

Comment: What exception did you get?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the connection refused. Might be I am missing something or doing it incorrectly, so can you please brief me what all things we need to do to setup multiple remote TSD instances for a single HBase instance with multi node clusters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you followed the instructions at http://opentsdb.net/setup-hbase.html to setup a single-node cluster, you'd need to remove the properties `hbase.zookeeper.dns.interface` and `hbase.regionserver.dns.interface` and `hbase.master.dns.interface` so that HBase and ZooKeeper don't bind to `localhost`.

Comment: I have successfully created the 4 node HBase cluster and now I was trying to transfer my data from single node hbase cluster to the multi node hbase cluster.Refering to your link http://opentsdb.net/setup-hbase.html, in which it was advised to use add_table.rb but in the never releases of hbase this file is missing , so can you please suggest its alternative?

Comment: Can you please guide me to create tsdb and tsdb-uid tables on hbase cluster? I copied the create_table.sh file to my Hbase master and executed the following: `env COMPRESSION=LZO HBASE_HOME=/home/ec2-user/minjar/hbase-0.94.12/ ./create_table.sh` , it says `ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times
` , though my master is running.Thank you in advance